How to NOT execute programs after location.replace()
When the following script is executed, "hoge" is displayed.
Why is "hoge" displayed instead of moving to the next screen even though location.replace() is executed first?
<script>
  (async function(){
      await new Promise((resolve)=>{
      location.replace("https://www.instagram.com"); // iOS Universal Links
      resolve();
      });
      alert("hoge");
  })();
</script>

What I want to do is as follows:

iOS: Universal link is triggered and the app is launched. This page is closed by window.close().
Non-iOS: The universal link is not triggered and this page transitions as is.

If I execute the following script on iOS instead of the previous one, the page is closed before the application starts up, and I am having trouble.
<script>
  (async function(){
      await new Promise((resolve)=>{
      location.replace("https://www.instagram.com"); // iOS Universal Links
      resolve();
      });
      window.close();
  })();
</script>

It works well if I use setTimeout() as shown below, but I don't want to use it if possible because I think it depends on timing.
<script>
  (async function(){
      await new Promise((resolve)=>{
      location.replace("https://www.instagram.com"); // iOS Universal Links
      resolve();
      });
      setTimeout(function(){window.close();}, 500);
  })();
</script>

Environment

iPhone 15 Pro Max
iOS 17.4
Safari.app


No browser is expected to execute anything after location change, with or without deferring. Also no browser is expected to close the browser window unless it has been opened by a script from the same domain.

Open it in a new tab instead. It works on windows, not sure about IOS
window.open("https://instagram.com/", "_blank")
window.close()


No browser is expected to close the browser window unless it has been opened by a script from the same domain. Did you try the script at all? Here at SO it gives a sandbox error and on the web it will give an access denied error.

@mplungjan It doesn't work when executed in 

Ok, how the OP has managed to close the window, I'm not entirely sure, probably by using some redirection technique. That's probably why it worked when I used console. The website could close itself somehow.

Thanks for discussing.
It worked perfectly for me.
I didn't need the "Promise", just the following
window.open("https://www.instagram.com"); // iOS Universal Links window.close();
But why doesn't the original script work?

I'm guessing that it's because replace doesn't block the execution of the rest of the program and will give a return before it the page has been redirected
